# Help Troubleshooting: Ubuntu 20.04 Sound Issue: Jumping / Repeating

Tags: drivers, sound, 20.04, hdmi, headphones

I'm worried this might be a hardware issue, but need help with how to troubleshoot it.

My Mobo died so I replaced it, turns out with a slightly updated version of the board, finally got everything back the way I had before (Dual boot etc.) and have now noticed that the sound is jumping, or repeating a fraction of a second, periodically - maybe every 30 seconds and then sometimes more frequently. Looking at resources, nothing is working particularly hard and there's no correlating spikes in say CPU or RAM. I had to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch in the end and I believe everything to be up to date.

This issue is occurring in Rhythmbox, VLC and Videos, it is also happing on Video / Browser and also have tested with headphones and TV via HDMI. GeForce 545

Have selected the proprietary video driver in case the card had some bearing on this and I think my sound is basically on-board rather than discrete.

Any ideas please?

Comment: I have since tested the sound in Windows and the issue doesn't seem to be occurring there, so wondering now about drivers? I don't have a sound card so not sure if there is a separate driver for sound?

Comment: I wouldn't say I have fixed the issue, but reinstalled Ubuntu this evening after testing the live disk and finding the issue had improved a bit. Had issues with the reinstall too though and couldn't do the third-party option.

Comment: After trying some of the similar threads relating to choppy audio, I had no joy. What appears to have worked is removing the pcie wifi card I had, which wasn't connected to any antennas and wasn't really working, this seems to have fixed the issue for me as it was directly underneath my double slot graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

A year late but I had the same issue, this was my fix.
From instructions here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure I ran

```
killall pulseaudio; pulseaudio -k  ; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*
```

waited a few seconds

```
pulseaudio --start
reboot
```

The additional 20.04 code mentioned on the page was not necessary on my system.

Also disable Wifi - This appeared to be the actual root cause!

Comment: Thanks, I am still having sound issues, Killing Pulse Audio solves for a while but then returns.

Comment: Make sure wifi is deactivated too. That may make other issue null.